# RavenDB Hierarchial Data Manipulation

Tags: ravendb

We have a Blog engine stored in RavenDB. The Blog Posts are separate documents to the Comments. What we need to do is to create an Index that retrieves our blog posts as normal but also includes a field for the sum of the comments (i.e. the count as a number) belonging to each Blog Post. Of course each comment document has the Blog Post Id as a foreign key.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to handle that is to do a map/reduce index that would count the number of comments per blog post. Then you query the index for the count as part of loading the blog post (you can do that using Lazy).

Comment: We thought about this and have created the Map/Reduce for the count. But not quite sure how to the last bit. We are getting a list of posts not just one. Could you provide a little help with a bit of code sample. Many thanks – user2981411 29 mins ago

Comment: `session.Query<BlogPostCounts.Result, BlogPostCounts>().Include(x=>x.BlogPostId).ToList()` - and then you run over that. Loading each blog post (which was already included into the session.